# Installation of Zend Framework in WampServer

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp

How to install Zend Framework in wampserver 5.2.6, anyone can help me?
And my wampserver is not in C:/ but it is in E:/ ,so can not work "ZF" in windows powershell.
I am new in Zend Framework, so please give me all steps for installation of Zend Framework in Wamp Server.

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download Zend Framework tarball / zip
2. Extract somewhere, lets say "E:/ZendFramework" for example
3. Edit your `php.ini` file and append the path to the `library` folder to your `include_path` directive

For example

```
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;E:\ZendFramework\library"
```

**Also, don't forget to restart / reload Apache**

### Update

You can also add the paths to the PHP binary folder and ZF `bin` folder to your PATH environment variable to make it easier to run the command line tools.

For Windows XP you can check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Comment: but after that how can i use that zend. I have make one zend project and open http://localhost/harikt-zendblog-1d6db04/public/ but is not open. i face this type of error.             Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\jimesh\wamp\www\harikt-zendblog-1d6db04\public\index.php on line 18

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path=';.;E:\jimesh\wamp\bin\php\zend\library') in E:\jimesh\wamp\www\harikt-zendblog-1d6db04\public\index.php on line 18

Comment: @hardcoder Provided the framework library is available on the include path, a default app created with `zf create project` should work

Comment: @hardcoder So the ZF library folder is definitely at `E:\jimesh\wamp\bin\php\zend\library`? Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: thanks it is working i have placed zend framework folder in wamp\bin\php, so, it is started. but can you tell me how can i create my new project. at this moment i have used already created project but i want to create my own project. if you have any website or pdfs then please send me url. and once again thanks.

Comment: @hardcoder with milestone Once you have set environment variables to php.exe and zf.bat . You can issue zf and see various helps . Can also go through http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Comment: hi Hari, I have tried to install zend framework but i got the error 403 forbidden because i have changed httpd-vhosts.conf file. so i have to uninstall wamp server and installed new wamp server.can you give me steps to easily install zend framework in wamp.can you help me? Thanks in advance.